# Overloaded unary operator ++ takes one parameter

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to overload an operator '++' in C#, but when I wrote following code, the VS 2012 give me an error message.

```
    public LogItem operator ++()
    {
        ++ visitTimes;
    }
```

The error is **Overloaded unary operator ++ takes one parameter**

And I here's the definition of **class** LogItem:

```
     public class LogItem
     {
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public LogItem(string ip)
        {
            ipAddress = ip;
            visitTimes = 0;
        }

        /**
         * Operator Overload Function
         */
        public LogItem operator ++() 
        {
            ++ visitTimes;
        }

        public string ipAddress { get; private set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public int visitTimes { get; private set; }
     }
```

What should I do to overload the operator '++'?

Comment: post your full code please

Comment: I have posted the full code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator need to be static member of its defining class and in case of `++` takes an argument of that type:

```
public class LogItem
{ 
    ....
    public static LogItem operator ++(LogItem item) 
    {
       item.visitTimes ++;
       return item;
    }
}
```

See [Operator overloading tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx) on MSDN for more samples.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading the unary operator ++ in C# overloads both the postfix and prefix versions of the operator.

See: http://devhawk.net/2003/07/09/operator-overloading-in-c/ http://www.programmingvideotutorials.com/csharp/csharp-operator-overloading